# Delegate method property to being triggered on conforming class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have the following `protocol`

```
protocol SentenceDelegate: class{
   func sentenceDidFinish()
}
```

I have my `SentenceMarkov` class conform to the protocol:

```
class SentenceMarkov : SentenceDelegate{
   // foo
   // bar
}
```

I implement the protocol method in my conforming class:

```
class SentenceMarkov : SentenceDelegate{
    //...
   func sentenceDidFinish{
      //Do something
   }
    //...
}
```

I create a property on the class that calls the protocol method called `sentenceDelegate` :

```
class otherClass{
    //..
    weak var sentenceDelegate: SentenceDelegate? 
    //..
}
```

I set this property in my first class to `self`

```
class SentenceMarkov{
var FirstOne:OtherClass {
    didSet { FirstOne.sentenceDelegate = self}
}
var SecondOne:OtherClass {
    didSet{ SecondOne.sentenceDelegate = self}
}

init(Ult:OtherClass, Penult:OtherClass){
    self.FirstOne= Ult
    self.SecondOne = Penult
    self.FirstOne.sentenceDelegate = self
    self.SecondOne.sentenceDelegate = self
}
//..
}
```

Finally I call the `sentenceDelegate` method in `OtherClass` after its `init()`

```
 class OtherClass{
    func sentenceDone(){
        sentenceDelegate?.sentenceDidFinish()
    }
 }
```

The problem is that, when I set breakpoints on the above method `sentenceDelegate` is `nil`. I am not sure why because I set it, although I could be setting it wrong, I am not sure how to ameliorate that though. Here is the three Swift files include the `ViewController` where `SentenceMarkov` is initialized:

https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/e1cb791dd165a6866e11
https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/263c9343e403c3a7ac40
https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/1400e7da024d78ba5ed0

Comment: Are you making sure that sentenceDone is called from `FirstOne` or `SecondOne` instance?

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar yes because I set a breakpoint there and it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
protocol Greeter: class {
    func greet()
}

class Dog {
    weak var greeter: Greeter?
}

class DogPound: Greeter {

    func greet() {
        print("Hi.  Welcome to the DogPound!")
    }

    var dog: Dog {
        didSet {
            dog.greeter = self
        }
    }

    init(dog: Dog) {
        self.dog = dog
        self.dog.greeter = self
    }

}

let myDog = Dog()
myDog.greeter?.greet()  //=>nil

DogPound(dog: myDog)
myDog.greeter?.greet()

--output:--
Hi.  Welcome to the DogPound!
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this is different from what I am doing in my code (in the gists). I create a `SentenceMarkov` object ( a DogPound) set the `sentenceDelegate` in the `didSet` on the two `Setences` or (Dogs) that belong to it, initialize the two `Sentences` before adding them to the `init` as you have done. Please tell me the difference.